# Retrieve data from Redis set

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I have stored some data in Redis using `Jedis`.
Now I want to retrieve set values if the key exists in the set.
I'm using `get` function but I end up getting this error:

> WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value.

```
String str = jedis.get(word);
```

To store data I have serialized my `Node` class using `toString` function.

```
jedis.sadd(word, toString(node));
```

`node` is an instance of `Node` class.

Comment: What code u used to store the data?

Comment: @Ankur updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a `set` in redis hence you need to use `set` related functions like `smembers`.

OR

You should be using `set` instead of `sadd` and then use `get` to read the value back.

Comment: `smembers` returns a set but I guess the value should be a String!

Comment: @Cyber: Then you should not use `sadd`. Use `set` and then use `get`.

Answer (score 0):

```
step 1 : You need to autowired redish

@Autowired
private RedisTemplate<String, Test> redisTemplate;

step 2 : KEY -> your key value for redis. ex. Your class name "Test" , 
testObj.id --> id of your obj and testObj --> your object

redisTemplate.opsForHash().put(KEY, testObj.id, testObj);

step 3 :  get Your object from redis. your key and object id. if you are 
need all object means

get single obj --> redisTemplate.opsForHash().get(KEY, id);

get need all object means  Map<Object, Object> obj=
```

redisTemplate.opsForHash().entries(KEY);

Comment: Why would I need to use Spring?